# rospackage command not found

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to install the package. I used the following command lines:-

> sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-rosserial

> rosstack profile

> rospackage profile

but it seem that rospckage profile command not found? What cause this? in before, all the installation went well. I use Ubuntu presice 12.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/129861/rospackage-command-not-found/) by [Ross Marry](https://answers.ros.org/users/8466/ross-marry/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-02-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The final command should be `rospack profile`

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ross Marry](https://answers.ros.org/users/8466/ross-marry/) on 2014-02-17**:
Thanks! It works.